# Converting an ELF executable (Linux) into a PE.exe (Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

I am a newbie when it comes to using machine code files!!!

I need to use a machine code executable obtained as ELF (Linux) into an exe file for Windows. I have tried 'objconv' but, though the format suggests to use '-fPE ', when I use that I get the command line indicates 'Error 2004 unknown command line' and 'Error 2103 cannot read input file'. I suspect that there is some incompatibility between Linus and Windows platforms

Comment: this won't work. Which tool do you try to convert? Look if there is already a Windows build.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to explain what you're trying to do, not how you're trying to do it. (You start by saying "I need to use ..." but don't explain *why* you need to do that. This makes it impossible to answer your question.)

Comment: What you're asking to do is impossible. However, you can get the ELF to run on Windows using Cygwin or a related tool, and you can get EXEs to run on Linux using WINE. And of course you could run everything in VMs.

Answer (score 1):

Although the underlying object code may be the same between the platforms, non-trivial native applications can't be binary-compatible between Windows and Linux.

If Linux executable you are trying to convert is dynamically linked, it would require the presence of libraries that don't exist on Windows (you can see this list of libraries by running `ldd /path/to/program` on the Linux machine).

Even if you converted all the libraries to PE executable format or statically linked them, the system calls to the [NT Kernel](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi_64/) and [Linux kernel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) are completely different. There is no direct one-to-one correspondence between them.

You best option would be to find the source code for the original application if possible. If the program is written in a portable way, it may compile on both Windows and Linux. Even though the system calls are not the same between the two platforms, a subset of their C library implementations have standardized behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly not going to work. Linux and Windows do not play nice with one another. The application you are looking to "convert" will have to be rebuilt from source for Windows (which will require Windows specific patching). With any luck the application you are trying to run already has a Windows port.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give this a read
https://github.com/microsoft/ebpf-for-windows/blob/main/docs/NativeCodeGeneration.md

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [*How do I write a good answer?*](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) Link-only answers are low quality. You can improve your answer by citing the most important fragments ([edit] the answer). Make sure they actually answer the question. If all you wanted to post is the link then this should go as a comment. [You need 50 reputation to comment freely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/355310). Not having enough reputation is not a reason to post a comment as an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1212708)